# Is there excessive lubricant on my new rear derailleur?

Tags: derailleur-rear, lubricant

I just received a new Shimano Deore rear derailleur, which has large gobs of lubricant in two locations (one clearly visible in photo). This seems excessive.

Do I leave it, or are they expecting you to wipe the excess away before installing?

[image: Deore RD, new]

Comment: Wipe it off, and any other visible globs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd wipe it off a bit--it won't serve any purpose as it is, apart from collecting dirt.

Comment: That was my concern, it would be a dirt magnet. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 8):

All of that goo is very typical of drivetrain components that are fresh from the factory. The factory uses a particularly thick lubricant to protect the parts until they're purchased or installed (lest they sit on a shelf and risk being exposed to moisture).

Basically, the factory is expecting whoever installs said drivetrain components to identify any excessive grease (some of it is there for good cause, such as protecting the inner spring from the elements), wipe it down, and re-lubricate with something lighter!

Comment: This is what makes New Old Stock items useful years later.   You find something that is exactly what you want, its been in the box 20 or 30 years, and is still factory-fresh.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, some reason why it was there in the first place. My guess was that maybe the grease was intended to distribute itself as you work the part during set-up, but your observation about long-term storage makes more sense.